# Why apply() instead of function invokation

Tags: function, kotlin, apply, invoke

The following code does the same thing. The functions **tr** and **td** take a *function literal with receiver object* as input in order to add tr or td tag inside of a table.

```
class TABLE : Tag("table") {
    fun tr(init: TR.() -> Unit) {
        children += TR().apply(init)
    }
}

class TR : Tag("tr") {
    fun td(init: TD.() -> Unit) {
        val td = TD()
        td.init()
        children += td
    }
}
```

My Question is why do I need to use **.apply()** instead of:

```
class TABLE : Tag("table") {
    fun tr(init: TR.() -> Unit) {
        children += TR().init()
    }
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the compiler looking for **init()** in the tr-object. But shouldn't this be decided on runtime?

Comment: Maybe the difference is that `apply()` returns the target of its invocation, so you can write `children += TR().apply()`... Did you try with `val tr = TR(); children += tr; tr.init()`?

Comment: That is right! I was looking for a complex solution whilst ignoring the simple ones. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in my comment, using `.apply` you can *chain* invocations of  `init` and `+=` together, because `apply` returns the target of its invocation.

If you prefer to use `init()`, you can obtain the same result with

```
val tr = TR()
children += tr
tr.init()
```

The key aspect of the *chained* variation is that the  apply`function of the Kotlin's standard library is defined as an extension function of a generic type`T`, accepting a *lambda with receiver` as its sole parameter, as you can see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html):

```
inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T
```

In order to explain its meaning, you can implement this function yourself:

```
fun <T> T.myApply(block: T.() -> Unit) : T {
    this.block()
    return this
}
```

The following example mimics your code, using a fake `MyClass` type in place of the original `TR`:

```
fun <T> T.myApply(block: T.() -> Unit) : T {
    this.block()
    return this
}

class MyClass(val text: String) {
    fun foo() : Unit {
        println("foo $text")
    }
}

fun initializer(mc: MyClass) {
    println("initializer ${mc.text}")
    mc.foo()
}

fun run(init: MyClass.() -> Unit) {
    val result = MyClass("first").myApply(init)
    val x = MyClass("second")
    x.init()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    run(::initializer)
}
```

You can play with this example in order to follow the flow from `run` to `MyClass.foo`, through the function accepting `init` as *lambda with receiver* parameter: I hope this can help you to clarify your understanding of the key charateristics of both the original and the alternative implementation of `tr`.